# Update the branch dev/jay/operation

Tags: git

I am very new with git, and I need your help for a certain task. I have the branch `dev/jay/operation`, I would like to update that branch from the remote repository. How could I do such thing? `git pull dev/jay/operation`? `git pull origin dev/jay/operation`? `git pull origin/dev/jay/operation`? Normally, I am able to update master with git pull origin master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull origin dev/jay/operation`

The syntax for git pull command is 
`git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]`

You can do `man git pull` for further information

Comment: Could I push with the same pattern : `git push origin dev/jay/operation`?

Comment: of course.. also it is adviable to set the upstream branch using `git push --set-upstream origin dev/jay/operation`

Comment: it did not work because I have `Your branch and 'origin/dev/max/operations-refact' have diverged,
and have 2 and 30 different commits each, respectively.`

Comment: what does `git branch -vv` produces .?

Comment: the remote branch at gitlab server have some additional changes wrt your local branch.. you can `git pull`, solve merge-conflict and then push again

Comment: yes, but `git pull` will pull by default from master. This is not what I want so far. I did pull from `dev/jay/operation`.

Comment: what is response for `git pull origin dev/jay/operation`?